# How to execute Linux command on Android/Java with low priority?

Tags: java, android, linux, exec

as the title already says, I want to execute a linux comand with a very low priority so as to not disturb my app and keep it running smooth.

I currently use:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec
```

Is there another way to achieve this with setting the priority ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the process priority on rooted devices with `renice` provided by the Busybox binary if you know the PID of the process you want to give less priority to.

Just run the command using the exec function of Runtime just like you are.