# How can i avoid android background process starvation?

Tags: android, process, su, thread-priority

I'm running a native background process from an android app with `Runtime.exec()`.

It seems like every few seconds the process is put to sleep for like 200 ms.
It looks like the android operating system is just starving that process.

Is there some way I can change the process priority from a background process to some other type of priority?

Assume the application that's running the process can get super user access.

**Edit:**

The command I'm using to run the process:

```
String fullCommand = "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=LD_LIBRARY_PATH:. && ./MyProc";

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c ", fullCommand });
```

Comment: Are you launching this process from inside application? Can you post a code how this process is launched?

Comment: few questions:
1. are you sure your local Runtime has su privileges (not the app)?
2. Runtime is not built for a prolonged action, what are you running there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the PID of the process, you can change its priority with `renice`
([taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9793034/2829009)).

You can call [renice](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/renice.1.html) like this:

```
renice priority [[-p] pid ...] [[-g] pgrp ...] [[-u] user ...]
```

Comment: I might be doing it wrong but this seems to have no effect

Answer (score -1):

Trying using the .setPriority() method.

```
 Thread t=new Thread();
 t.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
```

Comment: It's running as a process, there are like 20 threads, and it looks like the whole process is being paused for like 200 ms. All the threads freeze.

Comment: It's a native process. not a java process.